# Special relativity and the electromagnetic field tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity

Ok, I've got an exam for general relativity in the next week and I'm working through a (special) relativity problem at the moment and I just cant seem to get the solution indicated at all and was looking for some guidance.

The problem is given below
[image: problem]

I have succeeded in showing part i) via two applications of the lorentz transform but part ii) has me stumped.

Clearly we arrive at only two coupled differential equations in $\tau$ of the form 
\begin{equation} m \frac{dv^0}{d\tau} = qEv^1\end{equation}
\begin{equation} m \frac{dv^1}{d\tau} = qEv^0\end{equation}

but I haven't been able to arrive at the relation indicated at all. I believe that $\tau$ is the proper time, in which case I think it is given by 
$$ dt = \gamma d\tau$$ 
but I'll admit that that I am not too confident on this. I can also solve the coupled equations to get $v^0(\tau)$ and $v^1(\tau)$ and I get a linear combination of exponentials with $\pm Eq/m$ as their exponents, but I can't see how to get $\gamma$ out of this.

Any help would be wonderful as I'm tearing my hair out a bit

EDIT: Going into more detail about what i've done so far, rather than converting from $\tau$ to $t$ straight away we start with the two differential equations (1) and (2). Rearranging (1) to get $v^1$ on its own and plugging into (2) we get, after a little bit of work:

$$ \frac{d^2v^0}{d\tau^2} = \frac{q^2 E^2}{m^2} $$

which has as a solution

$$v^0 (\tau) = A e^{qE\tau/m} + B e^{-qE\tau/m}.$$
For A and B some constants of integration.
Plugging this into our first equation, we find that 
$$v^1 (\tau) = A e^{qE\tau/m} - B e^{-qE\tau/m}.$$

This is as far as I'm fairly sure on my answer. I've tried one or two other things but they all quickly led me to a dead end, in particular I tried using $dt = \gamma d\tau$ where $\gamma$ is the standard lorentz factor in the differential equations, where I would then arrive at things like
$$ m\gamma \frac{dv^0}{d\tau} = qEv^1$$ 
but solving these equations became much more tricky since (I believe) $\gamma$ depends on time as it is a function of velocity which is changing.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious though, as I seem to not be getting anywhere at all.

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit in showing what you've tried to do so far? Also, it'd be nice if you could actually type up the assignment rather than linking an image.

Comment: I edited to add more detail on what I've tried and managed to do, as you will see, its not a lot! Sorry about the image, I'm not well versed on the etiquette of posting here and it seemed the best way to put the question in without the chance of any mistakes creeping in!